# How to check state of terminal in Paramiko

Tags: python, shell, ssh, paramiko

**tldr**

Is there a way to check a shell in Paramiko to see if it has finished executing a command?

**Long**

We are trying to automate some fairly mundane server tasks on AWS. We've made good progress with Paramiko and boto3, but are running into a few roadblocks with building out our base AMI's.

The following gives us an interactive shell to work with:

```
def create_ssh_channel(instance, keypair):
    # we need to convert the string into a file-like object
    rsa_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(io.StringIO(keypair.key_material.decode()))

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname=instance.public_dns_name, username='ubuntu', pkey=rsa_key, )

    channel = ssh.invoke_shell()

    return channel
```

We can then issue useful commands across to it:

```
channel.send('sudo apt-get update')
channel.send('\n')
```

And read from the stream:

```
stream_data = str()
while True:
    if channel.recv_ready():
        stream_data += channel.recv(9999)
    else:
        break
```

This has let us do most things fairly reliably, including fetching external resources, piping out logs to other services etc.  Where we are getting stuck is when we need to run sequential commands, that rely on the first command being completed.  For example, we need `sudo apt-get install python-pip`, followed by `pip install lxml`.

The problem is that while most commands give fairly regular updates to the shell to read from, not all do.  We have tried a few ways to get around this, including breaking the loop with the following `if stream_data.endswith(':~$ ')`, but this has been hit-and-miss at best.

Is there a reliable way to check that the last-executed command has finished in a Paramiko shell?